# How to find KeyStore info in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-keystore

I have one keystore file `(.JKS)` for my android application lower version and i want develop new version of this application, with this keystore but i forget my `Key Store Password` , `Key Alias` and `Key Password` . 
How I can change or reestablish them?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools which will find the alias in an keystore file, but there is no easy way to extract the password from it.

[Here is a tool](http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/) that lets you try to find the password using dictionary attack as well as brute-force.

Comment: tnx my dear friend <3 . how to use this tools and link? tnx